# Old nautical word for the wooden pin you tie sail ropes to?

Tags: single-word-requests

It serves as a kind of 'lynchpin', but another word for that.

You can also take it out and use it as a bat, to bash Pirate's heads in.

I think there are a bunch of them all around the bottom of the mainmast, or maybe they are along the sides.

Comment: Did you mean *Bludgeon*? “I'll bludgeon you.” Though Josh is correct with the description you gave.

Comment: @Christopher - Nope, but thank you ..for taking a swing!

Comment: then your going to have to give us a few more clues.

Comment: [Clubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_%28weapon%29) *baton* jumps out, as does *cudgel* and *cosh*

Comment: @Christopher - Good call though; looking now at the etymology of [bludgeon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bludgeon).

Comment: Whatever the word your looking for is, @josh61 answer is 'pretty much' the correct one for the question you've asked.

Comment: I already acknowledged that below.  I'll give it a day or whatever to see if someone can come in and save the day, but otherwise Josh will win the check-mark.  (Or am I supposed to put all my extra comments up into the body of the OP?)  I realize that many want that check-mark granted now, _need_ that check-mark granted now - but **"No"**.  Not yet.  : )

Comment: I wouldn't put your comments in the question. and editing it now would possibly render existing answers obsolete. Probably best to ask another question. Pop into chat and ask a mod what you can do?

Comment: A different sort of nautical pin, beginning with 't' is a [thole](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thole)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Belaying pin](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belaying_pin):

> - ***A belaying pin is a solid metal or wooden device used on traditionally rigged sailing vessels to secure lines of running rigging.*** Largely replaced on most modern vessels by cleats, they are still used, particularly on square rigged ships.(Wikipedia)

[image]

[Belaying pin](http://www.seatalk.info/cgi-bin/nautical-marine-sailing-dictionary/db.cgi?db=db&view_records=1&uid=default&Term=lay):

> - 1) A stout bar of metal or wood shaped so that the bottom half slips through a hole in a rail at the mast partners or between the shrouds, to which halyards may be secured. (The pin is removable so that a hitch that binds can be easily freed.)
> - 2) ***The pin can be used as a club***, which gives the term a secondary ironic meaning: one can “stop” someone by hitting him with a belaying pin.

(The Dictionary of English Nautical Language Database)

Comment: … That is _exactly_ what I asked for.  But it's a different word.  Maybe there is a hierarchy of different types of belaying pins?  Or an older term?  Drats.

Comment: Also - I may have gotten the question entirely wrong, but I think the word I'm looking for has come to mean more of a menacing and violent object, if perhaps tongue-in-cheek.  _“I'll belaying-pin you.”_ doesn't work.

Comment: @ipso Do you mean a [marlinspike](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlinspike#/media/File:Marlingspike.JPG)?

Comment: @Dan – great call - as is the related [Fid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fid) - but not what I was thinking of.  At considerable risk of being wrong, I think my mystery word _might_ begin with a “T” - or at least all the not-quite words running through my head start with T.

Comment: @ipso Well, a T-word for something you beat someone with is a *truncheon*. But that doesn't have nautical origins.

Comment: @DanBron But *Third Officer does*

Comment: Yeah, I thought of [truncheon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truncheon), but that is not nautical,

Comment: ipso, just a random point, you often hear "Belay that order!" (meaning basically "hold that order, pause on it, stop doing what I said for now"). It's just possible that's the phrase you had in mind?

Comment: FTR, you're not just thinking of "cudgel" are you ?  is it just possible you're thinking of "stave" .. as in "I'll stave your head in mate!"

Comment: @ipso: are you saying that you're aware of a phrase that uses this term  "I'll {name of this nautical thing} you" and that you cannot remember the name, or are you hoping there's a word that you can use this way?

Comment: **JOE BLOW** is the man.  Since no one here has come up with it, I'm forced to reconsider, and am now thinking I must have gotten my wires crossed.  I'm thinking now what must have happened is Clark Gable or someone said _“belay that order”_, and I looked it up just out of curiosity and was surprised to see what “belay” meant.  It was no doubt **the order itself** that was menacing and violent.  Probably, what?  _Mutiny on the Bounty (1935)_?  Yikes.  Sorry folks!!

Comment: There is a nautical term **bitt**.  but that, I think, is for securing "lines" that hold a boat to a dock, rather than for securing rigging ropes to the boat.

Answer (score 2):

Option: archaic Anglo-Saxon.  Trumper -- a small handled tool used by sailers to secure knots in loops or running ropes and strands.

Lino-type operators used a Trumper, an oblong piece of loose lead shaped like a gullet to mark the break in a sentence or phrase that they knew would ultimately need attention by an editor.